# PHP : return html in $.ajax

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, html, ajax

I am trying to return HTML through `$.ajax`, this is my code:

```
 $(document).ready(function() {

    $(".click").on('click',function() {                
      var id= $(this).attr("data-id"); 

      $.ajax({     
        type: "POST",
        url: "getevents.php", 
        data: {id:id}, 
        dataType: "html",                  
        success: function(response){                    
            alert(response);
            $('.headimg').html(response);
        }
     });
 })})
```

**My PHP code:**

```
 $singleevent = mysqli_query($link, "SELECT `content` FROM `events` WHERE `id` 
= $id") ;
if(!$singleevent){
    echo mysqli_error();
}
else {

$result = mysqli_fetch_array($singleevent); 
 echo $result; 
}
```

**Link to be clicked:**

```
<a class='click' data-id='<?=$rows["id"];?>'><?=$rows['title'];?></a>
```

In alert() this is what I get **Array**

If I do print_r() instead of echo this is what I get

```
 [0] => <div class='row'>
  <div class='col-sm-12'>
   <img src='img/img.png' class='img-responsive'>
  </div>
  <div class='col-xs-12'>
   <p> October 14th  | All Day</p>

  </div>

</div>
    [content] => <div class='row'>
  <div class='col-sm-12'>
   <img src='img/img.png' class='img-responsive'>
  </div>
  <div class='col-xs-12'>
   <p> October 14th  | All Day</p>

  </div>

</div>
```

How to I put it in HTML rather than array?

Comment: maybe in your javascript, your html string is the first element of the array. try `$('.headimg').html(response[0]);`

Comment: try the `Array.join` function in JavaScript: `$('.headimg').html(response.join(''));`

Comment: You have typos in your code: `echo $reseult; ` instead `$result`

Comment: Your code is vulnerable to SQL injection attacks. You should use parameterised queries and prepared statements to help prevent attackers from compromising your database by using malicious input values. http://bobby-tables.com gives an explanation of the risks, as well as some examples of how to write your queries safely using PHP / mysqli. **Never** insert unsanitised data directly into your SQL.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The result is what you get if you do `echo array(1,2,3)`, you can not echo a array. Besides that, a PHP array isn't a Javascript array, so javascript doesnt understand the result.

You currently fetch the result from the database, which has two values because you fetch it as fetch_array(), which returns the data double:
- Once as numerical values ([0],[1],[2] etc)
- Once as named values (['content'],['example'],['etc'])

To remedy this, use fetch_assoc(). That will only return the last one *(the named)*.

But, then you still have an array with a value, so javascript will still get "Array" as you try to echo that. You can now do `echo $result['content'];` to fix this.

---

There is a (IMO) better method, which is a bit more complex, but a lot more expendable (what if you want 2 or 3 or ... values returned?), which is called JSON format.

In PHP you do `echo json_encode($result);` which will result in a weird look array in text format. Now you go to you Javascript AJAX function and add `dataType: "json"` to it. You can now use `response.content`, or `response.example`, or `response.whateverYouSelectInPHP`